# synchronized class variable within synchronized block

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I am looking at some api code which contains synchronized block and within this block there is a synchronized Map with default hashmap object;

Is this correct way?

Why the map is synchronized with default hashmap and again this class variable used in synchronized block?

Will it cause any memory leak?

```
public class Foo
{
  static Map synchronizedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap());

  public static String insertValue(String value)
   {
    String key = getKey(value);
        if(!synchronizedMap.containsKey(key))
        {
           synchronized (Foo.class) {
              synchronizedMap.put(key,"somevalue");
            }
         }
        return key; 
    }


   private static String getKey(String value)
   {
     return value+"::"+"1234";
   }

  public static boolean deleteValue(String value)
   {
       String key = getKey(value);
        Object obj = null;
       synchronized (Foo.class) {
        obj = synchronizedMap.remove(key);
    }
    if(obj == null)
           return false;
      return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile, because `obj` cannot be used outside the synchronized block in which it is declared.

Comment: Additionally, this code isn't thread safe, because of the non-atomic `containsKey` and `put` in the `insertValue` method.

Comment: @Andy, I corrected the code but, my question is it thread safe and will it cause any memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

The synchronization of the hash map appears trivial. Since the synchronized block is a class level lock and the map is a class level object only, the locking provided by synchronized lock is sufficient. 
Yes, this can be improved by maybe replacing the synchronized block and synchronized hashmap and using a concurrent hashmap.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not thread-safe:

`insertValue` checks if a value is present outside the synchronized block, but not again once inside. Therefore another thread could put in another value at the same time, which would then be overwritten by one of those threads.

In general the [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) is far superior to your implementation and you should use that. It would trivialize your methods:

```
public static String insertValue(String value) {
  final String key = getKey(value);
  map.putIfAbsent(key , "somevalue");
  return key;
}

public static boolean deleteValue(String value) {
  final String key = getKey(value);
  return (map.remove(key) != null);
}
```